# Windows Phone 8 C# - Autofill form textbox upon entering page in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Im working on a Windows Phone 8 App that would fill out a particular webpage's form textboxes upon navigating to the page.

The code Im looking for would be something similar to this:

```
     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          MiniBrowser.Source = new Uri(site, UriKind.Absolute);

          MiniBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ElementIdHhere").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text);
          MiniBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ElementIdHhere").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text);
```

}

However, Windows Phone platform doesnt seem to have support for WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById. Is there a way to do this in Windows Phone enviroment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to interact with the loaded content of the WebBrowser control is via JavaScript. The internals of the page are not made available to managed code.

This solution would also be dependent upon the HTML being loaded not preventing you from executing an `eval` method.

The other thing to consider that is not covered by the code in your question is that this will not be possible until the contents of the page have finished loading and this is not something you can see from managed code. You'll probably have to wait a few seconds to be sure it has finished rendering and can successfully process your JavaScript commands.

Comment: It finally works! 
WebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('tbVerotunnus').value = 'VALUEHERE';");